# Merge replication deleting data on the subscriber

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012, replication

I have two servers with Sql Server 2012, and with Merge replication configured.  They were working correctly, but because a network problem, the Subscriber was some days off line, and when the connection returned, the Publisher is deleting the data that was saved on the Subscriber during the off line period.  I tried to delete and reconfigure the Replication, but not working.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: How about you post process and error messages?

Answer (score 0):

The publisher might be marking records to be deleted on the subscriber because they don't exist on the publisher anymore. If this is not the case, reinitialize the subscription to the publisher on the client machine, and see if it starts replicating successfully.